# Not able to insert values in table in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert values in database ,but not able to do that

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$contactnumber=$_POST['contactnumber'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$qualification=$_POST['qualification'];
$postappliedfor=$_POST['postappliedfor'];
$sql_connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin","interview");
mysql_select_db("interview,$sql_connection") or die("cannot select DB");
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `USERDEATILS`(`id`,`fullname`,`contactnumber`,`email`,`qualification`,`postappliedfor`) VALUES('','$fullname','$contactnumber','$email','$qualification','$postappliedfor')");
if($sql){
        echo "done";
    }
    else{
        echo "There is an error!!"; 
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Please format your stuff correctly.

Comment: Surely `USERDEATILS` should be `USERDETAILS`?

Comment: no change,still not inserting

Comment: should i show you the whole page

Comment: You should show the error message. `There is an error` does not help. What we need is output of [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). Also note that all `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead (and still report what went wrong, not just that something went wrong).

Comment: thnku for your time ,but problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

change the line
 mysql_select_db("interview,$sql_connection")

to

mysql_select_db("interview", $sql_connection)

Comment: i did this but no change

Comment: can you show me the structure of the USERDETAILS table?

Comment: id         int(250)    AUTO_INCREMENT 
 fullname        varchar(250) 
        contactnumber varchar(250) 
 email 
 qualification int(250)    
 postappliedfor int(250)

Comment: according to that, the column email should be given a type, like varchar. if your id is set as AUTO_INCREMENT you don't need to use that column in your query, also when you are inserting an integer you must not use quotes in your value. Try this:



    INSERT INTO `USERDETAILS`(`fullname`,`contactnumber`,`email`,`qualification`,`postappliedfor`) VALUES('$fullname','$contactnumber','$email',$qualification,$postappliedfor)

Comment: actually i followed your instruction,but again there was no change but then i changed the form action ,earlier action was to go on some other page but now i gave action for the page itself

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Manuel Ramirez said, you might want to check to make sure your mysql data type 'id' isn't set to NOT NULL. You also may want add the to auto_increment property to the 'id' field, so you can ommit it when inserting records

Answer (score 0):

**Use proper syntax of mysql :**

```
$sql_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

remove `database_name` from `mysql_connect`.

In `mysql_connect` we can only pass `5` parameters **:**

1. Server
2. username
3. password
4. new_link
5. client_flags

**But i will suggest you to use MySQLi that would be like this:**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```